# Should we flag up which Buddhist tradition we practice with?

Tags: discussion, answers, community, traditions, profile-page

Just a thought / random idea.

One of the interesting things about the site is that people from different traditions all contribute to the site. Hopefully it will continue and grow.

When I am reading answers I am interested in which part of Buddhism they practice with or identify most with. Could we/should we gently suggest that people might like to put on their biographies which branch of Buddhism they practice with if any. Or maybe which teachers they are particularly inspired by. I might help to know they are 'coming from'

As I say just an idea

Comment: Yeah, I do tend to click on people's profiles to see if there's any identifying information about their tradition. It should be pretty clear which branch I'm from.

Comment: in the interest of transparency it is important to know where people are coming from. I like on reddit how you can have your "theravada" tag next to your name etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think putting in our profiles is a good idea.  I also think that if our answer or question deals if from a particular branch of Buddhism, then we should tag thusly.

Anyone want to take a crack at generating tags?   As a side-note, what would you call Thich Nhat Hanh's branch of Zen.  "Zen"? "Thich Nhat Hanh" (even if it's not personally related to him)? "I ♥ Thay"?

Comment: Re: tagging questions - see also http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19/28

Comment: I believe the proper term is Plum Buddhism

Comment: I think we need tags like Goenka, Mahaisi, Pa Auk, etc. by traditions variations established by different teachers so we can understand the relation between them.

Answer (score 1):

Indicating which tradition the users follow is a great idea indeed.

Personally, however, I would not dare to state who my teachers are, out of deepest respect. My participation on SE is purely based on personal and limited understanding and should not be linked to the teachers I trust. My poor and confusing answers shall not discredit my teachers.